# Date Time compare on diffrent computers

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, utc, data-conversion

I have configuration file where i can set and store time in below format:

```
06:00:00 AM or 01:00:15 PM
```

then i am using this time (loadconfig.GetTimeFromConfigThen) as below to compare with current time within my service which is running every second:

```
  Dim Time As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")
            If Time = loadconfig.GetTimeFromConfigThen
..
```

the problem is when i went on other server where the format of datetime is diffrent in regional settings, even if e.g 06:00:00 AM is reached it will never go inside my if loop because i am comparing strings and on the other server Time variable was appearing as: "6:00:00 a.m.".

My question is how to change that comparmision that no matter what format is installed on server it will correctly compare the time from config to pc time? I want to keep this format within conmfig file as mentioned: `06:00:00 AM or 01:00:15 PM`

Comment: Always use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture when you parse config files.

Comment: can you give some example?

Answer (score 0):

You should store your date value in an unambiguous way, and use DateTime variables to perform your comparison with rather than strings.

I suggest you use the [Round Trip format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#Roundtrip):

`DateTime.Now.ToString("o")`

On my machine this outputs:

`2015-08-18T11:09:23.0918585+01:00`

As I am 1 hour ahead of `UTC`

To read this in you can use

`Dim serverDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2015-08-18T11:09:23.0918585+01:00", "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Which will correctly preserve and adjust the time zone information using the current locale.

You can then work out the difference from this time using a TimeSpan:

`Dim ts As TimeSpan = DateTime.Now - serverDate`